# multiple ng grids and ngGridEventScroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

On a single page I have 2 separate ng grids with infinite scrolling, loading server-side data on `ngGridEventScroll`.

`scope.$on('ngGridEventScroll', function(event) { ... });`

Each grid makes its own unique server-side call to load data specific to each specific grid.

But since I can't 'namespace' the `ngGridEventScroll`, both grids trigger on the scroll event any time either grid generates the event.

How can I 'scope' the `ngGridEventScroll` event to more specific so each grid can listen to only its scroll event and not both?

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the ng-grid source code, and it does not pass any context information when it raises this event.

Look for this string in source code

`$scope.$emit('ngGridEventScroll');`

You can update this call, with some context information you want to pass in the emit function.

Comment: Yes, I saw that too, and I would like to add some context information to the emit function, but how to do that without touching the nggrid code itself? On another note, I figured out that I can match the grid that emitted the event by checking the event's target and current scope against each other: event.currentScope[namespace].gridOptions.gridId !== event.targetScope.gridId  The 'namespace' variable you see here is something we had to attach to our own $scope to keep track of the different grids.